# Insert column from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy a column from one table to another.

The number of rows is equal in both tables. The values I want to copy from table2 to table1 are unique. I've tried a few thing, but none so far work. My code is:

```
insert into alleoppdragpunkter3
select Idtall
from IDtall
```

Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The request for procedure 'IDtall' failed because 'IDtall' is a table object.

I would like my column from table2 to be in table1.

Comment: Are they in the same database/schema/server or different?

Comment: @dfundako They are in the same database

Comment: `SELECT * INTO table1 FROM table2`. This creates a new table with the name table1 and the content of table2

Comment: @schlonzo Yes, but I have two tables I want to combine, but not by using the join function, because then I loose my unique values I want as a new column. If something like this was possible it would be nice:
SELECT * INTO table1 FROM table2 AND table3

Answer (score 2):

You can try below-

```
insert into alleoppdragpunkter3(col1,col2,col3,....)
     select col1,col2,col3,.... from IDtall
```

Comment: Did not work :( Error message: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @gustavhf, you need to specify your column name I've edited my answer - you can check now

Answer (score 0):

You do not copy *columns* between tables.  You can insert *rows* and update *columns*.

Perhaps you want:

```
update p
    set p.<col> = i.<col>
    from alleoppdragpunkter3 p join
         idtall i
         on p.? = i.?;
```

The `?` is for the column that specify the `join` conditions between the tables.  The `set` references the column you want to update and which value to take.

Comment: Thanks! It works fine! My problem with this is that the new column I now insert don't have only unique values anymore. The join condition makes it so that some of the values occur multiple times instead since the column I join with does not only have unique values.

Comment: @gustavhf . . . You should ask a *new* question.  Include sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you need.

Comment: Okay! I can do that! Thank you for help :)